# Class with property that is a List Of items in a subclass

Tags: vb.net, class

I want a class for a Customer, with a text property name.
Another property CustAddress will be a list of multiple addresses.
Each address will have two string properties.

Here is what I have.
I am not sure if I need something in the constructor of the class address.
And I'm even not sure what the code would look like to exploit this class.

Also, I can't get the F11 Step Into debug feature to step into the class code.  If i put a break in the class code it does break and works fine.  I have modified the option "Just My Code" to remove checkbox, but it does not help.  I have a solution containing one class module and one Windows App together.

```
<ComClass(ComClass1.ClassId, ComClass1.InterfaceId, ComClass1.EventsId)>
Public Class ComClass1
#Region "COM GUIDs"
    ' These  GUIDs provide the COM identity for this class 
    ' and its COM interfaces. If you change them, existing 
    ' clients will no longer be able to access the class.
    Public Const ClassId As String = "c8e723b4-f229-4368-9737-97c4c71d490a"
    Public Const InterfaceId As String = "16275ddb-5cfe-47c0-995f-84a5f868ad1b"
    Public Const EventsId As String = "dad73a5c-8ac4-4384-a5f9-8e2c388b5514"
#End Region
    ' A creatable COM class must have a Public Sub New() 
    ' with no parameters, otherwise, the class will not be 
    ' registered in the COM registry and cannot be created 
    ' via CreateObject.

    'Fields  
    Private _name As String
    Public _CustAddress As List(Of address)

    'Constructor for class ComClass
    Public Sub New()
        _CustAddress = New List(Of address)
    End Sub

    Public Property CustName() As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _name = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property CustAddress() As List(Of address)
        Get
            Return _CustAddress
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of address))
            _CustAddress = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Class address

        Private _address1 As String
        Private _address2 As String

        Public Sub New()
            '??????
        End Sub

        Public Property Address1 As String
            Get
                Return _address1
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                _address1 = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property Address2 As String
            Get
                Return _address2
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                _address2 = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class

End Class
```

Comment: You don't have a question specified. Can you explain better? Do you want the code for the constructor of address class?

Comment: Why do you think you might need code in the `address` constructor? What do you think such code would achieve that your current code does not?

Comment: Why is the backer field (_CustAddress) for the Public Property CustAddress also public?

Comment: Yes it seems my post lacked a specific question.

Comment: Will this class as written allow me to instantiate a customer object and assogn multiple addresses to that object.

Comment: If not then what do I need to change.  If it will, what would the code be to utilize the class to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took out the com stuff just to shorten the answer. Since you had no extra code in the Property Procedures I shortened that to automatic Properties. I also moved the address Class out on its own. This class could be useful else where in the program so a nested class is not really necessary.

```
Public Class ComClass1
    Public Property CustName As String
    Public Property CustAddress As List(Of address)
    Public Sub New(cName As String, cAddresses As List(Of address))
        CustName = cName
        CustAddress = cAddresses
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class address
    Public Property Address1 As String 'Street Address
    Public Property Address2 As String 'City and State
    Public Sub New(a1 As String, a2 As String)
        Address1 = a1
        Address2 = a2
    End Sub
End Class

Private Sub DeclareAComClass1()
    Dim addrList As New List(Of address) From {
        New address("12 Main Street", "Los Angeles, CA"),
        New address("13 Park Avenue", "New York, NY")
    }
    Dim cc As New ComClass1("Big Company, Inc.", addrList)
End Sub
```

Comment: Mary,. Can I still use this as a com class?  I have read that a com class does not support parameters on the constructors.  I need to use this class from VBA.

Comment: I agree that a stand-alone address class would be useful,  But in this case i am trying to understand subclasses.   Also, the text about com class and not supporting constructors with parameters lead me to think that having a subclass that is not exposed would mean I can use parameterized constructors in my subclasses and still use the main class  as a com class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have ended up with.  @Mary got me further ahead.  But because I am using a COM class, I can't have any public constructors with parameters.

I added a method called AddAddress which gives me the functionality I need.
In my original post I somehow left out MyBase.New which is required for a COM class.

I encourage comments with insights on this approach.

```
<ComClass(ComClass1.ClassId, ComClass1.InterfaceId, ComClass1.EventsId)>
Public Class ComClass1
#Region "COM GUIDs"
    ' These  GUIDs provide the COM identity for this class 
    ' and its COM interfaces. If you change them, existing 
    ' clients will no longer be able to access the class.
    Public Const ClassId As String = "c8e723b4-f229-4368-9737-97c4c71d490a"
    Public Const InterfaceId As String = "16275ddb-5cfe-47c0-995f-84a5f868ad1b"
    Public Const EventsId As String = "dad73a5c-8ac4-4384-a5f9-8e2c388b5514"
#End Region
    ' A creatable COM class must have a Public Sub New() 
    ' with no parameters, otherwise, the class will not be 
    ' registered in the COM registry and cannot be created 
    ' via CreateObject.

    'Fields  
    Private _name As String
    Private _CustAddress As List(Of address)

    'Constructor for class ComClass
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New
        _CustAddress = New List(Of address)
    End Sub

    Public Sub AddAddress(a1 As String, a2 As String)
        Dim addr As New address(a1, a2)
        _CustAddress.Add(addr)
    End Sub

    Public Property CustName() As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _name = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property CustAddress() As List(Of address)
        Get
            Return _CustAddress
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of address))
            _CustAddress = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Class address

        Private _address1 As String
        Private _address2 As String

        Public Sub New(a1 As String, a2 As String)
            _address1 = a1
            _address2 = a2
        End Sub

        Public Property Address1 As String
            Get
                Return _address1
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                _address1 = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property Address2 As String
            Get
                Return _address2
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                _address2 = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class

End Class
```

And the code to implement/test is as follows:

```
Dim TestClass As New ComClass1
        Dim myint As Int32

        TestClass.CustName = "John Smith"
        TestClass.AddAddress("123 Main Street", "Los Angeles")

        TestClass.AddAddress("13 Park Avenue", "New York")

        Debug.Print(TestClass.CustAddress(0).Address1)   '123 Main Stree'
        Debug.Print(TestClass.CustAddress(1).Address1)   '13 Park Avenue

        TestClass.CustAddress.Remove(TestClass.CustAddress(0))

        Debug.Print(TestClass.CustAddress(0).Address1)    ' 13 Park Avenue
```

Comment: Great! The only thing I see it in the Constructors (Sub New). Assign the parameters to the Public Properties instead of the Private backer fields (the ones that begin with an underscore. It if good practice because there may be code in the Property procedure. You know way more about COM than I do. Too bad you can't use automatic properties. I guess you are using an old version of VS.